# Transactions and aggregator

Tags: spring-integration

I've seen the aggregator's code and as far as I understand, it does the following ops:

add message to group
if the group can be released then:
   complete group and send it to output/reply channel
   if (expire-groups)
      remove group and messages from message store
   else remove only messages

here I need some ACID transactional support to do all or nothing, but after reading the docs, I couldn't find how to do so. Could you please tell me if it's possible and if it is, how can I achieve this?

thanks in advance

Regard
Guzman

Comment: What do you want within the scope of the transaction? All the adds and the release? Or something else.

Comment: the add of one message and the remove of all the messages in the group  after the release

Answer (score 0):

You can make the inbound (Direct) channel to the aggregator transactional...

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="send" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="aggTx" expression="execution(* *.send(..)) &amp;&amp; bean(toAggChannel)" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="aggTx" />
</aop:config>
```

That will handle normal delivery and release.

To make exipiring partial groups transactional, use a `MessageGroupStoreReaper` and make the `MessageGroupStore.expireMessageGroups()` method transactional in a similar way.

You cannot currently expire partial groups in a transaction when using `group-timeout` or `group-timeout-expression`.